# replace last 2 characters with one in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to search for .. and replace it with a .
I also need to ignore ... and leave it alone.

Example in notepad++

**Find what**: `([.]{2})`
**Replace with**: `.`

So

```
course they'll be...
worried.. about you..
```

should be

```
course they'll be...
worried. about you.
```

Comment: what if you have `hello..world` ? or `..` will always be followed  by space or end of string

Comment: Should it replace four dots to two? `....` to `..`?

Comment: @code, It's for subtitles. It either has eg. Hello world i'm... 3 dots indicates a person hasn't finish speaking his sentence and was interrupted. Obviously end of sentence has a full stop . The two dots is simply an error and thus needs to be 1 dot ie full stop.

Comment: @Pushpesh, subtitle edit is already coded to deal with 4 dots or more by reducing it to 3.

Comment: @user10246830: Ok, in that case Tim's answer is enough for you, which I think you told me already in a comment of my answer which I removed as that was no longer needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
Find: (?<!\.)\.\.(?!\.)
Replace: .
```

The logic here is to use a lookaround on each side of the two dots to assert that in fact they are not part of a longer sequence.

### Demo

Comment: Another approach would be searching for `\.\.(\.)?` and replacing with `(?1$0:.)`. BTW +1

Comment: @tim, That worked well when using subtitle edit multiple replace. It won't work for xml file using notepad++  <RegEx find="(?<!\.)\.\.(?!\.)" replaceWith="." />. Says ? The preceding token is not quantifiable

Comment: @user10246830 I have answered the actual question you asked.  In general, you should not use regex to update XML content.  Use a parser instead.

Comment: @Tim, your answer was perfect, no problem. Regex is part of the xml file, used by subtitle edit to correct misspelling of subtitle files.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the checkmark tip, couldn't understand why your answer wasn't at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Find: `(?&lt;!\.)\.\.(?!\.)` worked for xml. `&lt;` replace `<` as in Tim's above answer.

`(?<!\.)\.{2}(?!\.)` for normal find and replace and `(?&lt;!\.)\.{2}(?!\.)` for xml equally worked.

Comment: You do not need to serialize `<` if you define the pattern inside an XML attribute. Use `CData` block: `<pattern><![CDATA[(?<!\.)\.{2}(?!\.)]]></pattern>`